# How to set eclipse to run a makefile that resides seperatly from the code

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile

I am running a small application that test a certain module in a large project.
to do so, I created a new makefile that includes few auxiliary files (like stub.h and so).
this make file is than uses the original makefile (in other location) to compile the original code (the one tested).

to make it clearer...

original code and makefile is in BigProj/General/Manager/makefile
my app and makefile are in       BigProj/General/emulator/apps/makefile

How can I instruct eclipse to show the source files from original code (BigProj/General/Manager), **BUT** build it from my app folder (BigProj/General/emulator/apps)?

Thanks,
AmiGal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project configuration panel (right click on the project folder in the project explorer, choose 
*Properties*, or press `Alt-Enter` if you are already visiting the project), select the *C/C++ Build* sub panel, then in the *Builder Settings* tab, change the *Build location* to the one of your liking.

Normally, it should point to your source location by mean of an eclipse project variable of the form `${workspace_loc:/BigProj/General/Manager}/` or something like that. It should be straightforward to replace the relevant part with your app folder name.